# Hedging of FX combo trade

Tags: fx

Say we’re selling a TRS on a local MSCI index denominated in USD and delta hedge it by buying eq futures on that local index denominated in local currency (non USD). Let’s also ignore repo/div/ir risk and only look at fx and funding.

One option would be to sell an fx spot (sell usd, buy local currency) replicating the proper fixing (WMCO for MSCI indices) on trade date to hedge the fx risk and then enter an fx swap for the maturity of the swap where we borrow USD and lend the local currency in order to flatten our cash balance during the swap life.
At the swap expiry we would do an fx spot opposite to what we did on trade date.

Question is: why could we not just sell an fx forward instead of an fx spot (on trade date and on expiry date) coupled with an fx swap?

If we could indeed do the hedge with just an fx forward, what maturity should we choose for the fx forward?